# trim a filename in-place before its moved

Tags: bash, rename

I am trying to use `rename` to edit or trim a filename in-place without using a `loop`. Both commands below execute but the filenames remain unchanged. In my actual data there are several filenames all in the format of `file`. Thank you  :).

**file**

```
19-0000-LastName-FirstName_v1_Non-Filtered_2019-03-21_08:12:56.txt
```

**rename**

```
rename "s/_v1_Non-Filtered_d+_\d+//" *.txt
rename 's/_.*?//' *.txt
```

**desired filename**

```
19-0000-LastName-FirstName.txt
```

Comment: Please add your rename version, and where is your replace-with string?

Comment: Please add your desired filename to your question.

Comment: You are missing a backslash before your first `d+`. It would also help if you showed what result is expected!

Comment: My apologies.... added to the post, I am trying to remove everything after and including the `_v1`. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is to rename files like:

```
19-0000-LastName-FirstName_v1_Non-Filtered_2019-03-21_08:12:56.txt
```

to:

```
19-0000-LastName-FirstName.txt
```

In English, based on the comments, that can be stated as:

> Remove everything after and including the `_v1` (except keep the extension)

This can done with a search and replace like:

```
rename 's/_v1.*(\..*)/$1/' *.txt
```

- match:

  - first occurrence of `_v1`
  - followed by as much as possible of anything (`.*`)
  - followed by a period (`\.`)
  - followed by anything (`.*`)
- because of the first `.*`, the explicitly matched period must be the final one
- parentheses `(`...`)` capture part of the match for later use (as `$1`)
- replace the entire match with the capture group

---

Notes:

- the pattern you provided includes a section `_d+_\d+` which, because of the missing `\` matches "underscore" "d" "+" "underscore" "one or more digits". This can never match against your filename. Perhaps you meant: `_\d+`
- `s/_.*?//` looks for `_` followed by the shortest possible sequence (`*?`) of anything (`.`). The shortest possible sequence of anything is the empty string. So, the command is equivalent to: `s/_//`

Comment: Thank you for thehelp and explanation :)